# How to do a helm push of only those files which have changed in Gitlab CI?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I have a git repository that has my helm charts. I want to create a CI pipeline for this repo which will do the helm package and push to my helm chart repository ( chartmuseum). I only want to package and publish those helm charts which have changed when committed to master. I can do a for loop and push all charts irrespective of whether they have changed but it take s along time since there are a lot of charts .

Gitlab -only:changes does not give me the file path of which file has changed
I am hoping git will do that, haven't found any solution yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git  diff --name-only ${CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA}...${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
```

was the answer for me.